# Finding limits for $\frac{1 - \cos(x)}{x}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I have some difficulties understanding the last step of the screenshot.

The first step is to multiple the conjugate of the numerator. The second step is to use $1 - \cos^2(x)$ to get $\sin^2(x)$.

How and why did the author splits the $\dfrac{\sin^2x}{x(1+\cos x)}$ into a limit with two functions in it.

Can anyone help to explain the intentions and how it is derived?

[image]

Comment: This is just multiplication of two function

Comment: @TonyMa I am trying to understand the 3rd equation.

Comment: Just split the function in the 3rd limit into two function, nothing changed

Comment: The splitting happens because $\sin x\over x$ has a known value as $x\to 0$.  Then the second fraction can be evaluated on its own, and it is easy to see that its value is $0$, giving the required result...

Comment: If $\lim_{x\to a^S} f(x)=L_1\in\mathbb R$ and $\lim_{x\to a^S}g(x)=L_2\in\mathbb R$ then $\lim_{x\to a^S} (fg)(x)=L_1 L_2$. Your case is $lim_{x\to 0}$, so that applies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ and taking that term out make things clearer as now when we substitue $0$ into the denominator, we no longer get $0$ but the numerator still give us $0$.

Since $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}=0$, the overall limit is $0$.

Comment: can I treat it as a algebraic equation (split the function in the 3rd limit into two function) where sin(x) is a^2 and x is c, 1+cos(x) is d. i.e. a^2/cd and splits it into a/c * a/d?

Comment: yes, but be careful that when we split the function, the limit should exists for each subterm.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Siong Thye Goh's answer:

Remember that "the limit of a product is the product of the limits", when each individual factor's limit exists, so that

$$ \lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}$$

$$ = \lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{\sin(x)}{x}  \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}$$

$$ = 1 \times 0 = 0.$$

The key point here is understanding why $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ tends to 1, as $x$ tends to 0, and then applying this limit; there are some great geometric proofs of this, if you just do a search here on this site.  (Note: I don't recommend that you verify this limit with l'hospital's rule, since it's very much circular reasoning.)

Comment: can I treat it as a algebraic equation (split the function in the 3rd limit into two function) where sin(x) is a^2 and x is c, 1+cos(x) is d. i.e. a^2/cd and splits it into a/c * a/d?